# After Hitting Button wait for Left click to do certain action

Tags: c#, forms

My question is:
How do I make a button in C# Forms wait for me to do MouseDown(Mouseclick) to execute a command?

Basically, When I press the button It waits for me to press Left Click and do the command that I have in the code.

The button going to be something like a gate, you press it and then you can do the action that I have in mind. (Like a safety feature you can do it unless you press the button and after that, you enable the next code to happen.)

After clicking the button being able to Left click and execute my code.
Not when I click the button.

Comment: For example, memorize that the button was pressed with a flag, and check the flag state in MouseDown event handler...?

Comment: Use a tag to check if the button was clicked.  Set the tag to clicked then perform your code.

Comment: @fana - How do I do that ? i tried searching on youtube or online but didnt find what i was looking for

Comment: I don't know what is your current real problem. Can you do this? : 
1. define a bool variable(used as flag). 2. initialize it as false. 3. change it's value to true when button pressed.

Comment: @fana ah is that what a flag is then It doesnt work i tried that already.

Comment: If so, adding the info "how/why simple flag is not enough" to question may be needed.